# Loading an image whilst flash swf is downloading. HTML

Tags: html, image, load, flash

i have a big flash file that loads in but takes a noticeable amount of time to download. Its a header and i was just wondering if i could have an image instantly appear and then when the flash is downloaded seamlessly overlap it?  Just wondering if there was an HTML to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **two** options for this as far as I can tell.

**- Option A** is the solution you've mentioned already. I would have an *img* tag inside the same *div* as the swf `position:absolute` and have flash do an `ExternalInterface.call("hideImage")` call to *JavaScript* when the swf is loaded and have the `hideImage` function in javascript remove/hide the img tag.

**- Option B** (which is what I would go with) is to use a preloader inside of *flash*. Set up two separate *keyframes* at the first of *flash*. I usu *label* my first one "loading" and the second one "main". In loading I have *actions* similar to the following:

```
// stop the playhead from moving ahead
stop(); // you can also use gotoAndStop("loading"); if you want

function loaderProgressHandler(event:Event):void {
    // switch the framehead to main which will show your content
    if(event.bytesLoaded >= event.bytesTotal) {
        event.target.removeEventListener(Event.PROGRESS, this.loaderProgressHandler);
        this.gotoAndStop("main");
    }
}

this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.PROGRESS, this.loaderProgressHandler);
```

*Flash* will show the "loading" *frame* segment once it loads, your swf won't switch to "main" until the rest of the *swf* is done loading. I'd recommend some sort of **preloader** with a percentage indicator if you *swf* is as big as you're saying.